# Counting flips for a binary counter

Tags: recurrence-relations, computer-science, boolean-algebra

$$T(n)=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\left\lfloor\frac n{2^i}\right\rfloor<n\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac1{2^i}=2n$$
$$\implies T(n)=O(n)$$
For context:
This calculates the number of flips for a binary counter.  I understand the theory behind it.  Each bit is flipped every $2^i$ times where $i$ is the index of the bit.  This equation sums every bit flip for each index in the binary number.

I am confused by the math and how to derive $2n$.

Also, why is the less than symbol there along with the 2nd part of the equation?

Comment: $\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac1{2^i}=2$  This is just a geometric series.

Comment: "=" means "is equal to" and "<" means "is less than", so the first line makes three claims. Do you understand why each of them is true?

Answer (score 1):

For $x>0$, trivially $\lfloor x \rfloor \le x$. This means that

$$T(n)=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\left\lfloor\frac n{2^i}\right\rfloor\le \sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\frac{n}{2^i}=n\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\frac1{2^i}.$$
Note that we're adding positive terms, so by adding more summands we get a bigger number, e.i. an upper bound.
$$\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\frac{n}{2^i}< n\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac1{2^i}.$$
The last sum is a geometric series, which easily evaluates to $2$. Now we have showed $T(n)<2n$, which obviously implies that $S=O(n)$. (You may prove it with the quantifier definition of $O$.